# UIScrollSlidingPages returns same view (last allocated view) for all views

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

i'm using UiScrollSlidingPages (https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages) plugin but i have a problem. The displayed view for every page is the same and it is the last one view allocated.

This is the method of datasource delegate that i'm using

```
-(TTSlidingPage *)pageForSlidingPagesViewController:(TTScrollSlidingPagesController*)source atIndex:(int)index{

variabiliGlobali.paginaFormazione = index + 1;
UIViewController *viewController;
viewController = [[foaPaginaFormazioneVC alloc] init];
return [[TTSlidingPage alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];

}
```

This is the foaPaginaFormazioneVC code.

```
#import "foaPaginaFormazioneVC.h"
#import "foaAppDelegate.h"
#import "foaVotoCalciatoreCell.h"
#import "foaBonusTotaliCell.h"
#import "foaRiepilogoCell.h"

@implementation foaPaginaFormazioneVC

foaAppDelegate *variabiliGlobali;

NSDictionary *formazione;
NSDictionary *elencoCalciatori;
NSDictionary *logFormazione;
NSDictionary *logCalcolo;

NSMutableArray *titolari;
NSMutableArray *panchinari;
NSMutableArray *logForTipo;
NSMutableArray *logForValore;
NSMutableArray *logCalTipo;
NSMutableArray *logCalValore;

bool calcolata;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cellZoomInitialAlpha = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    self.cellZoomAnimationDuration = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
    self.cellZoomXScaleFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9];
    self.cellZoomYScaleFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9];

    variabiliGlobali = (foaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    formazione = [variabiliGlobali.formazioniA objectAtIndex: variabiliGlobali.paginaFormazione - 1];


    elencoCalciatori = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    logFormazione = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    logCalcolo = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    if ([formazione objectForKey:@"FORMAZIONE"] != [NSNull null]) {
        elencoCalciatori = [formazione objectForKey:@"FORMAZIONE"];
    }

    if ([formazione objectForKey:@"LOG_FORMAZIONE"] != [NSNull null]) {
        logFormazione = [formazione objectForKey:@"LOG_FORMAZIONE"];
    }

    if ([formazione objectForKey:@"LOG_CALCOLO"] != [NSNull null]) {
        logCalcolo = [formazione objectForKey:@"LOG_CALCOLO"];
    }


    titolari = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    panchinari = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in elencoCalciatori) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"ORDINE"] intValue] <= 11) {
            [titolari addObject: dict];
        }
        else {
            [panchinari addObject: dict];
        }

    }

    logForTipo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    logForValore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    logCalTipo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    logCalValore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *appString;
    bool appBool;
    float appNumber;

    if ([logFormazione count] != 0) {
    //AMMINISTRATORE
    appBool = [[logFormazione objectForKey:@"AMMINISTRATORE"] boolValue];
    if (appBool) {
        [logForTipo addObject: @"Formazione inserita dall'amministratore"];
        [logForValore addObject: @""];
    }

    //MODULO INIZIALE
    appString = [logFormazione objectForKey:@"MODULO_INIZIALE"];
    [logForTipo addObject: @"Modulo Iniziale"];
    [logForValore addObject: appString];

    //DATA
    appString = [logFormazione objectForKey:@"DATA"];
    [logForTipo addObject: @"Data Ultima Modifica"];
    [logForValore addObject: appString];
    }

    if ([logCalcolo count] != 0) {

    //MODULO FINALE
    appString = [logCalcolo objectForKey:@"MODULO_FINALE"];
    [logForTipo addObject: @"Modulo Finale"];
    [logForValore addObject: appString];

    //PORTIERE IMBATTUTO
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"PORTIERE_IMBATTUTO"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Portiere Imbattuto"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    //MOD_P
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"MOD_P"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Modificatore Portiere"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    //MOD_D
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"MOD_D"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Modificatore Difesa"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    //MOD_C
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"MOD_C"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Modificatore Centrocampo"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    //MOD_A
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"MOD_A"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Modificatore Attacco"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    //PUNTEGGIO
    appNumber = [[logCalcolo objectForKey:@"PUNTEGGIO"] doubleValue];
    if (appNumber != 0) {
        NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:appNumber];
        [logCalTipo addObject: @"Punteggio Finale"];
        [logCalValore addObject: [doubleNumber stringValue]];
    }

    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata) {
        return 4;
    }
    else {
        return 3;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSInteger *numero;

    //La giornata è calcolata. Sezione 2 = BONUS e TOTALI
    if (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && section == 2) {
        numero = [logCalTipo count];
    }

    //La giornata è calcolata. Sezione 3 = RIEPILOGO
    //La giornata non è calcolata. Sezione 2 = RIEPILOGO
    if ((variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && section == 3) || (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata == false && section == 2)) {
        numero = [logForTipo count];
    }



    if (section == 1)
    {numero = [panchinari count];}

    if ( section == 0)
    {numero = [titolari count];}

    return numero;


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *idDettCal = @"cellaVotoCalciatore";
    NSString *idRiepilogo = @"riepilogoCell";
    NSString *idTotali = @"bonusTotaliCell";

    //Dictionary per Titolari e Panchinari
    NSDictionary *calciatore;




    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 1) {

        foaVotoCalciatoreCell *cell = (foaVotoCalciatoreCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idDettCal];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idDettCal owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        //TITOLARI
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            calciatore = [titolari objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        //PANCHINARI
        else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            calciatore = [panchinari objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        NSString *calciatoreStr =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
         [calciatore objectForKey:@"CALCIATORE"],
         @" (",
         [[calciatore objectForKey:@"SQUADRA"] substringToIndex:3],
         @")"];


        NSString *imgRuolo =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
         [calciatore objectForKey:@"RUOLO"],
         @".jpg"];

        cell.ruolo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgRuolo];


        NSDictionary *dettaglioVoto;
        UIImageView *imageIcona;
        CGFloat offset;
        dettaglioVoto = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_STM"];

        offset = 0;
        for (NSString *icona in dettaglioVoto) {
            if ([icona isEqualToString: @"AMMONITO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amm.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_FATTO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golfatto.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_SUBITO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golsubito.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ENTRATO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"entrato.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"USCITO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uscito.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ESPULSO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"esp.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ASSIST"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"assist.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ASSIST_FERMO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"assistf.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_SEGNATO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoresegnato.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_SBAGLIATO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoresbagliato.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_PARATO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoreparato.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"AUTOGOL"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"autogol.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_PARTITA"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golvittoria.png"]];
            }
            else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_PAREGGIO"]) {
                imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golpareggio.png"]];
            }

            imageIcona.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, imageIcona.frame.size.width, imageIcona.frame.size.height);
            //imageIcona.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, 20, 20);
            offset = imageIcona.frame.size.width + offset + 2;
            [cell.iconeDettaglio addSubview: imageIcona];
        }

        if (offset == 0) {
            //cell.calciatore.frame = CGRectMake(cell.calciatore.frame.origin.x, 14, cell.calciatore.frame.size.width, cell.calciatore.frame.size.height);
        }

        cell.calciatore.text = calciatoreStr;
        cell.votoIniziale.text = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_PRNT"];
        cell.votoFinale.text = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_PRNT_TOT"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;

    }
    //La giornata è calcolata. Sezione 2 = BONUS e TOTALI
    else if (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && indexPath.section == 2) {

        NSDictionary *totaliVal;
        NSDictionary *totaliTip;

        totaliVal = [logCalValore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        totaliTip = [logCalTipo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        foaBonusTotaliCell *cell = (foaBonusTotaliCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idTotali];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idTotali owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.tipoBonusLabel.text = totaliTip;
        cell.totaleLabel.text = totaliVal;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;

    }

    //La giornata è calcolata. Sezione 3 = RIEPILOGO
    //La giornata non è calcolata. Sezione 2 = RIEPILOGO
    //else ((variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && indexPath.section == 3) ||
    //     (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata == false && indexPath.section == 2)) {

    //}

    else {
        NSDictionary *riepilogoVal;
        NSDictionary *riepilogoTip;

        riepilogoVal = [logForValore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        riepilogoTip = [logForTipo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        foaRiepilogoCell *cell = (foaRiepilogoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idRiepilogo];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idRiepilogo owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.voceRiepilogoLabel.text = riepilogoTip;
        cell.valoreRiepilogoLabel.text = riepilogoVal;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }



}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSString *header;

    if (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && section == 2) {
        header = @"Bonus e Totale";
    }

    if ((variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && section == 3) || (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata == false && section == 2)) {
       header = @"Riepilogo";
    }



    if (section == 1)
    {header = @"Panchinari";}

    if ( section == 0)
    {header = @"Titolari";}

    return header;

}


@end
```

If i use another simple view (with only one random label) the plugin works fine.

What is the matter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my question declaring these variable

```
NSDictionary *formazione;
NSDictionary *elencoCalciatori;
NSDictionary *logFormazione;
NSDictionary *logCalcolo;

NSMutableArray *titolari;
NSMutableArray *panchinari;
NSMutableArray *logForTipo;
NSMutableArray *logForValore;
NSMutableArray *logCalTipo;
NSMutableArray *logCalValore;

bool calcolata;
```

in .h files of ViewController.